# What does this 'Bottomless Carafe' do?

Tags: the-witcher-3, the-witcher-3-hearts-of-stone

During my travels in The Witcher 3: Hearts of Stone expansion pack, I came into possession this little item called the 'Bottomless Carafe'.

It's description reads: "Provides an endless supply of hard alcohol. This spirit is distilled from scorpion tails."

This sounds quite useful, as I've spent quite a tidy sum of crowns on various alcohols for alchemy, and I was hoping that this item would allow me an unlimited amount of some ingredients, but alas - when I tried to made things using various alcohols as ingredients, they all seemed to be taken up still. Have Geralt and I been duped? If we have not, how do we go about using this trinket?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, I just wanted to add the definition of a 'carafe' for anybody else who had never heard the word, like I did:
"an open-topped glass flask typically used for serving wine or water."
Google gives results that make them look pretty much like a vase, but meant for drinking stuff out of.

Comment: ... but meant for 'serving wine or water out of'.

Comment: @Tylor a good equivalent is also a coffee urn, which also uses the word "carafe" to describe it. Brew a pot of coffee into a carafe and put it in the middle of a table at a meeting, and nobody has to get up for a refill.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Given to you by Gaunter O'Dimm as a reward for a certain story path.

The choices given by Gaunter determine the reward:

1. **Wanna be as swift as the wind.** 
   [Caparison of Lament](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Caparison_of_Lament) - *The saddle appears to be fashioned of strange leather, the hide of some unknown beast. As evidence of its unusual nature, suffice it to say that it is always rather warm to the touch. The saddle addles the mind of a randomly-selected opponent within a limited range.* Transforms Roach into a black horse with red eyes, black smoke particle effect. Has Axii and stun effects on nearby enemies.
2. **Never wanna go hungry again.** [Horn of Plenty](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Horn_of_Plenty) - *Provides an endless supply of food. The horn of plenty seems alive and pulses while producing food.* Endless food item useful for health regen.
3. **A bottle of vodka that's always full.** [Bottomless Carafe](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Bottomless_carafe) - 
   *Provides an endless supply of hard alcohol. The spirit is distilled from scorpion tails.* Endless supply of alcohol used when meditating to replenish alchemy items.
4. **Make me rich.** 5,000 crowns
5. **Don't want anything from you.** You get nothing.

The player is likely to be overflowing with alcohol, food, and crowns late-game, it seems the best choice would be the saddle.

Credit to the Witcher wikia for item information and journal descriptions.

Comment: I hope there's a mod out there that keeps the effects of the saddle without making roach look like an edgelord.

Answer (score 18):

When he meditates, Geralt consumes one "Strong Alcohol" to replenish *all* bombs and potions.

What the bottomless Carafe offers is never needing a "Strong Alcohol" to restock your alchemical items.

Comment: seems pretty useless to me, alcohol is one of the few things I never run out of.  Now if I had such a thing in real life...

Comment: What a shame, has quite lower value than one may expect from how much you end up going through to get it. Ah well. I decided to be safe and pick an option that couldnt seem to hurt me. Low risk, low reward.

Comment: Well, on my last playthrough on highest difficulty, I actually had some troubles getting all that alcohol for my potions. However, at the point where you can obtain this carafe, you should have enough strong alcohol for a lifetime.